# SQL Server 2008 R2 query related to replacement of data

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a scenario wherein I  have to remove all the strings except a or b or c

My sample table is as follows:

```
Id     Product
------------------
1.     a,b,Da,c
2.     Ty,a,b,c
3.     a,sds,b
```

Sample output

```
Id    Product
----------------
1.     a,b,c
2.     a,b,c
3.     a,b
```

My current version is Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: So what is your expected output here? What version of SQL Server, and (most importantly) is that delimited data you're storing in a single column there; and if so, why?

Comment: Yeah I am storing it in a single column as they all come under a common tag..

Comment: You say replace it with `''`, however, your output doesn't represent that. I would for example expect `a,b,Da,c` to become `a,b,,c` is you were replacing it with a blank string, Are you saying you want to **remove** these elements?

Comment: OK, but storing delimited data is still a bad idea. Also, you haven't tagged your version yet. Please do so; it makes a (big) different to the answer.

Comment: Exactly....I want to remove those elements along with either the preceding or following comma

Comment: And your version is..? ( I can only ask this so many times). Thanks.

Comment: Microsoft SQL server 2008 R2 is the version I am using currently...also can u let me know the alternate to storing delimited values..thanks in advance..

Comment: Update your tags and question with SQL Server 2008 R2.  It will be more likely to get you the help you want.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you out. As I state in the comments, I make use of Jeff Moden's [DelimitedSplit8k](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/), as you're using an older version of SQL Server. if you were using 2016+, you would have access to `STRING_SPLIT`. I also normalise your data; as storing delimited data is almost always a bad idea.

```
CREATE TABLE #Sample (id int, Product varchar(20));

INSERT INTO #Sample
VALUES (1,'a,b,Da,c'),
       (2,'Ty,a,b,c'),
       (3,'a,sds,b');
GO

--The first problem you have is you're storing delimited data
--You really should be storing each item on a separate row.
--This is, however, quite easy to do. i'm going to use a different
--table, however, you can change this fairly easily for your
--needs.

CREATE TABLE #Sample2  (id int, Product varchar(2));

GO
--You can split the data out by using a Splitter.
--My personal preference is Jeff Moden's DelimitedSplit8K
--which I've linked to above.
INSERT INTO #Sample2 (id, Product)
SELECT id, Item AS Product
FROM #Sample S
     CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(S.Product,',') DS
WHERE DS.Item IN ('a','b','c');
GO
--And hey presto! Your normalised data, and without the unwanted values
SELECT *
FROM #Sample2;

GO

DROP TABLE #Sample;
DROP TABLE #Sample2;
```

If you have to keep the delimited format, you can use `STUFF` and `FOR XML PATH`:

```
WITH Split AS(
    SELECT id,
           Item AS Product,
           ItemNumber
    FROM #Sample S
         CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(S.Product,',') DS
    WHERE DS.Item IN ('a','b','c'))
SELECT id,
       STUFF((SELECT ',' + Product
              FROM Split sq
              WHERE sq.id = S.id
              ORDER BY ItemNumber
              FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
FROM Split S
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply...But I want that to be in the same cell as I have a scenario of normalising it based on one more condition actually....so can u just let me know if I can have that in the same cell as a delimited value..thanks in advance

Comment: @vamseedharankalyanakrishnan added how to create a delimited list as well; however, I still suggest you normalise your data.

Comment: Heyyy...also is there some other approach to this without using DelimitedSplit8k...just curious to hear

Comment: There are, yes; I suggest having a search yourself though. Asking how to split a delimited list in SQL Server is probably one of the most common questions on SO. You'll learn more if you do the research yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This also will do the thing, using xml only:

```
select * into #t from (values('a,b,Da,c'),('Ty,a,b,c'),('a,sds,b'))v(Product)
;
with  x as (
    SELECT t.Product, st.sProduct
    FROM #t t
        cross apply (
            SELECT CAST(N'<root><r>' + REPLACE(t.Product,',', N'</r><r>') + N'</r></root>' as xml) xProduct
        )xt
        cross apply (
            select CAST(r.value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)') as nvarchar) sProduct
            from xt.xProduct.nodes(N'//root/r') AS RECORDS(r)
        ) st
    where st.sProduct in ('a', 'b', 'c')
)
select distinct x.Product, REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(cleared.cProduct), 2, 999)) cleared
from x
    cross apply ( select (
        select distinct ref.sProduct + ','
        from x ref
        where ref.Product = x.Product
        for xml path('') )
    )cleared(cProduct)
;
drop table #t
```